# How do I prevent my laptop from shutting down when undocking?

Tags: laptop, docking-station, hp-elitebook

The Laptop is an HP EliteBook 8540p running Windows 7 Professional. OS updates are applied regularly via Windows Update and the machine is currently fully up to date.

Recently, when undocking the laptop it has started initiating the shutdown sequence.  The "waiting on applications to close" box pops up so it can be aborted if caught quickly enough.

I can't find anything in the power configuration related to docking/undocking and google hasn't proven very useful either.  Has anyone ran into this problem and figured out how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore to a point before this started happening to see if it still does it?  Anything new/suspicious in the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Have you checked HP's site for driver/firmware updates? Possible something Windows Update changed will be fixed by updating them.

Comment: I'll check and see if there is a new BIOS update available, I know HP puts those out pretty regularly, perhaps an update caused an issue that they resolved there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally stumbled across something that seemed to work, though it was for a newer model HP elitebook running Win 7 Pro 64-bit.

In this case, the 'Power Options' settings options seemed to trigger the 'when I close the lid' action upon being undocked. I changed it Sleep, saved changes, then back to Do Nothing and saved the changes. At this point the laptop behaved as expected during the undock.

I tried this because I noticed that the lid close event seemed to be firing, despite being set to Do Nothing.  It looks as though the value it reads to display the setting may not be the same value that is looked at to determine the action, and that they somehow got out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for my laptop by changing the power options in system settings for what happens 'when I close the lid' and 'when I press the power button' to *Do Nothing*.

Comment: The person who originally asked this question seems to have solved it, and your answer is pretty much the same as his.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Firmware and Video Drivers to see if that corrects the issue. Worked for me.